# what this error means 'org.json.JSONObject'?

Tags: java, spring-boot, javabeans

**QuestionController Class:**

```
package app.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import app.model.Question;
import app.repository.QuestionRepository;

/**
 * @implNote Controller Class to manage Questions http operations
 * @author usardar
 *
 */
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/question")
@CrossOrigin
public class QuestionController {

    @Autowired
    private JSONObject json;

    @Autowired
    private QuestionRepository questionRepository;

    @Autowired
    private Question question;

    /*
     * Usage: Example: http://localhost:8080/question/retrievequestions 
     * Output: [ {"qId":3, "title":"Who is the founder of Dawn news?", "optA":"Quaid-E-Azam", "optB":"Usama", "optC":"Ali Hassan", "answer":"Quaid-E-Azam"} ]
     */
    @GetMapping("/retrievequestions")
    public List<Question> getQuestionsList() {
        List<Question> questionsList = questionRepository.findAll();
        if (questionsList != null) {
            return questionsList;
        }
        return questionsList;
    }

    /*
     * Usage: 
     * Example: http://localhost:8080/question/addquestion
     * Post Request : {"title":"Who is the founder of Pakistan?", "optA":"Quaid-E-Azam", "optB":"Usama", "optC":"Ali Hassan", "answer":"Quaid-E-Azam"}
     * Output: [ {"success", "Question Inserted Successfuly"} ]
     */
    @PostMapping("/addquestion")
    public String addQuestion(@RequestBody String newQuestionObj) {
        System.out.println(newQuestionObj);
//      json = new JSONObject(newQuestionObj);
        question.setQuestion(json.getString("newQuestion"));
        question.setOptA(json.getString("newOptA"));
        question.setOptB(json.getString("newOptB"));
        question.setOptC(json.getString("newOptC"));
        question.setAnswer(json.getString("newAnswer"));
        questionRepository.save(question);
        json.clear();
        json.put("success", "Question Inserted Successfuly");
        return json.toString();
    }

}
```

This is my class for reference.

Error message:
Field json in app.controller.QuestionController required a bean of type 'org.json.JSONObject' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
- @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.json.JSONObject' in your configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to inject a class that is not a Spring Bean:

```
@Autowired
private JSONObject json;
```

As in the commented out code simply instantiate the object:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(newQuestionObj);
```